# sfdx export products and related custom object

Tags: apex, soql, salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin, product

I have a custom object, `myObject__c` and on the `Product2` object we have a field (`Product2.myObject_lookup__c`) that is a lookup to the `myObject__c` object. I need to export the relationship between `Product2` and `myObject__c` so that I can import the data into a sandbox that was recently refreshed. However, I cannot export the `Product2` and `myObject__c` records together.

**Question**

1. How can I export the records for both objects such that they create the same data in a sandbox?

**What we tried but no success**

```
sfdx force:data:tree:export -u myTargetUsername --query "select id, (select id from product2) from myObject__c" --prefix data-export mydir/targetFolder --plan
```

**Alternative that didn't export the myObject__c records, only Product2**

```
sfdx force:data:tree:export -u myTargetUserName --query "select id, myObject_lookup__r.Name, myObject_lookup__r.field1__c, myObject_lookup__r.field2__c from Product2" --prefix data-export mydir/targetFolder --plan
```

**Error message**

```
Error at Row:1:Column:28
If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

Comment: Did you check if user has access to this custom object and the field on product2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the inner soql query , you have to use plural label appended with __r.

go to product2 object, open the lookup field with custom object.
note down child relationship name.
lets say child relationship name is products, then you have to use products__r in inner query.

select id, (select id from Products__r) from myObject__c

Comment: that is what i was missing, thanks